# Increasing or decreasing height for an SVG element in IE 10 always keeps a constant space in the document

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg, jquery-svg

I am using html5 svg graphics to draw lines. When I increase or decrease the height of an svg element, it changes the height of the svg element but also keeps a constant space between the svg element and the document end. This happens only with IE browser. I'm using IE10.

The svg element is placed inside a div element. Height is set only for the svg element, height and width properties are not defined for the div element.

At first, I thought using clipping was the reason and I tried it after removing all the clippings and still there is a constant space between the svg element and end of the document in IE 10.

I attached images showing the difference between IE10 and Chorme below:

Chrome:

[image]

IE10:

[image]

Is there any way to avoid this additional space in the document?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but that looks like Chrome, not Firefox.

Comment: @joey yes its chrome browser.

Comment: Some code would be helpful...

Comment: sorry, I mistakenly typed firefox instead of chrome

Comment: Do you have anything on `:hover`?  Could be [this bug](http://blog.brianrichards.net/post/6721471926/ie9-hover-bug-workaround) if so.